# Removing whitespace on hidden table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a system where clients have enrollments for different things and details are shown in a table. I have set clients who have multiple enrollments to have a table row that has a clickable dropdown to show other enrollments. However, when the row dropdown is not initially clicked, there is whitespace rows in the table for the hidden rows. How can I remove this whitespace?

[image: Searchable dashboard table with clients with enrollments]

Here is my code.

Javascript:

```
$('.enrollment-toggle').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('client-id'));
  if ($(this).children('i').hasClass('fa-caret-right')) {
    $(this).children("i").removeClass("fa-caret-right").addClass("fa-caret-down");
  } else {
    $(this).children("i").removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-right");
  }
});

$('.table tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).remove();
});​

$('.table tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).css("display","none")
});
```

HTML:

index.html.erb

```
<section class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
  </section>
</section>
<input type="text" id="searchable-dashboard-table" class="form-control" placeholder="Search dashboard table.. (case sensitive)" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<section class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-12">
    <section class="panel panel-default">
      <section class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Past Due Enrollments</h3>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <div class="btn-group actions">
            <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export All Tabs'.html_safe, dashboards_path(format: 'xlsx'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="panel-body">
        <section role="tabpanel">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#current" aria-controls="current" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Current</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#30days" aria-controls="30days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">30 Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#60days" aria-controls="60days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">60 Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#90days" aria-controls="90days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">90 Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#120days" aria-controls="120days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">120+ Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#no-payments" aria-controls="no-payments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">No Payments</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <section class="tab-content">
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="current">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @current_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="30days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @thirty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="60days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @sixty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="90days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @ninty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="120days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                </section>
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @one_twenty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="no-payments">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @no_payment_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

_enrollment.html.erb

```
<% client_enrollment_ids = enrollment.client.client_enrollments.pluck(:id) rescue [] %>
<% if @enrollments_ids.include?(enrollment.id) %>
  <tr class="client-enrollment-<%= enrollment.id %>">
    <td>
      <% if client_enrollment_ids.length > 1 %>
        <a class="enrollment-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseEnrollment-<%= enrollment.client.id %>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEnrollment-<%= enrollment.client.id %>" data-client-id="<%= enrollment.client.id %>">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= enrollment.name %></td>
    <td><%= enrollment.try(:client).try(:first_name) %></td>
    <td><%= enrollment.try(:client).try(:last_name) %></td>
    <td><%= enrollment.try(:program_status).try(:status) %></td>
    <td><%= ldate enrollment.last_payment_date %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.last_payment_amount %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.total_amount_charged %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.total_amount_paid %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.total_amount_due %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.payment_agreement_amount %></td>
    <td class='actions'>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to 'Action', '#', title: 'View Record', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to '<span class="caret"></span>'.html_safe, '#', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, title: 'More Actions', class: 'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' %>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <% if enrollment.client %>
            <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show'.html_safe, service_provider_client_client_enrollment_path(enrollment.service_provider, enrollment.client, enrollment), title: 'View Record' %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <% enrollment.client.client_enrollments.where("client_enrollments.id != ?", enrollment.id).each do |e| %>
    <tr class="secondary-enrollments collapse card card-block client-enrollment-<%= e.id %> collapseEnrollment-<%= e.client.id %>">
      <td><i class="fa fa-angle-right secondary-enrollment-indicator"></i></td>
      <td><%= e.name %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:client).try(:first_name) %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:client).try(:last_name) %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:program_status).try(:status) %></td>
      <td><%= ldate e.last_payment_date %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.last_payment_amount %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.total_amount_charged %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.total_amount_paid %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.total_amount_due %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.payment_agreement_amount %></td>
      <td class='actions'>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <%= link_to 'Action', '#', title: 'View Record', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          <%= link_to '<span class="caret"></span>'.html_safe, '#', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, title: 'More Actions', class: 'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' %>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% if e.client %>
              <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show'.html_safe, service_provider_client_client_enrollment_path(e.service_provider, e.client, e), title: 'View Record' %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the JS code for the search within those tables.

dashboard.js

```
var searchTable = function(event) {
  var searchText = event.target.value;
  console.log(searchText);
  var $tableBody = $("table tbody tr");

  // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
  $tableBody.each(function(index, row) {
    var hasMatch;
    var $row = $(row).text();

    hasMatch = ($row.includes(searchText));
    hasMatch ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide()
  });
}

$("#searchable-dashboard-table").keyup(searchTable);
```

I have tried working within Chrome Dev Tools and changing some CSS things to see if it would fix this issue, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

To view more information, go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp).

```js
$('.enrollment-toggle').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('client-id'));
  if ($(this).children('i').hasClass('fa-caret-right')) {
    $(this).children("i").removeClass("fa-caret-right").addClass("fa-caret-down");
  } else {
    $(this).children("i").removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-right");
  }
});

$('.table tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
index.html.erb

<section class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
  </section>
</section>
<input type="text" id="searchable-dashboard-table" class="form-control" placeholder="Search dashboard table.. (case sensitive)" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<section class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-12">
    <section class="panel panel-default">
      <section class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Past Due Enrollments</h3>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <div class="btn-group actions">
            <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export All Tabs'.html_safe, dashboards_path(format: 'xlsx'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="panel-body">
        <section role="tabpanel">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#current" aria-controls="current" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Current</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#30days" aria-controls="30days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">30 Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#60days" aria-controls="60days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">60 Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#90days" aria-controls="90days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">90 Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#120days" aria-controls="120days" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">120+ Days</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#no-payments" aria-controls="no-payments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">No Payments</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <section class="tab-content">
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="current">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @current_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @current_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="30days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @thirty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @thirty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="60days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @sixty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @sixty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="90days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @ninty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @ninty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="120days">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                </section>
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @one_twenty_day_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @one_twenty_day_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="no-payments">
              <section class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Enrollment</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Program Status</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Last Payment Amount</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Charged</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                      <th>Total Amount Due</th>
                      <th>Amount Due Per Agreement</th>
                      <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%= render partial: 'enrollment', collection: @no_payment_enrollments %>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:last_payment_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_charged_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_due_total] %></td>
                      <td><%= number_to_currency @no_payment_enrollments_totals[:total_amount_paid_total] %></td>
                      <td class='actions'>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </section>
            </section>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>






_enrollment.html.erb

<% client_enrollment_ids = enrollment.client.client_enrollments.pluck(:id) rescue [] %>
<% if @enrollments_ids.include?(enrollment.id) %>
  <tr class="client-enrollment-<%= enrollment.id %>">
    <td>
      <% if client_enrollment_ids.length > 1 %>
        <a class="enrollment-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseEnrollment-<%= enrollment.client.id %>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEnrollment-<%= enrollment.client.id %>" data-client-id="<%= enrollment.client.id %>">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= enrollment.name %></td>
    <td><%= enrollment.try(:client).try(:first_name) %></td>
    <td><%= enrollment.try(:client).try(:last_name) %></td>
    <td><%= enrollment.try(:program_status).try(:status) %></td>
    <td><%= ldate enrollment.last_payment_date %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.last_payment_amount %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.total_amount_charged %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.total_amount_paid %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.total_amount_due %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency enrollment.payment_agreement_amount %></td>
    <td class='actions'>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to 'Action', '#', title: 'View Record', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to '<span class="caret"></span>'.html_safe, '#', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, title: 'More Actions', class: 'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' %>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <% if enrollment.client %>
            <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show'.html_safe, service_provider_client_client_enrollment_path(enrollment.service_provider, enrollment.client, enrollment), title: 'View Record' %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <% enrollment.client.client_enrollments.where("client_enrollments.id != ?", enrollment.id).each do |e| %>
    <tr class="secondary-enrollments collapse card card-block client-enrollment-<%= e.id %> collapseEnrollment-<%= e.client.id %>">
      <td><i class="fa fa-angle-right secondary-enrollment-indicator"></i></td>
      <td><%= e.name %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:client).try(:first_name) %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:client).try(:last_name) %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:program_status).try(:status) %></td>
      <td><%= ldate e.last_payment_date %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.last_payment_amount %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.total_amount_charged %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.total_amount_paid %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.total_amount_due %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency e.payment_agreement_amount %></td>
      <td class='actions'>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <%= link_to 'Action', '#', title: 'View Record', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          <%= link_to '<span class="caret"></span>'.html_safe, '#', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, title: 'More Actions', class: 'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' %>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% if e.client %>
              <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show'.html_safe, service_provider_client_client_enrollment_path(e.service_provider, e.client, e), title: 'View Record' %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, it would be great if you could post your HTML as pure HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If collapse doesnt work, maybe try styling the "tr"  to display:none

I think you can do like this:

```
$('.table tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).css("display","none")
});
```

Second part of answer from comments put here since comment doesn't format.---

sorry to be saying try this and try that but... try $(this).css("display","none") instead of $(this).hide() ...

```
$tableBody.each(function(index, row) { 
  var hasMatch; 
  var $row =  $(row).text(); 
  hasMatch = ($row.includes(searchText)); 
  hasMatch ? $(this).show() : $(this).css("display","none") 
})
```

Comment: This worked for the table without any value in the search bar, but the blank rows are still present if there is a value present in that search bar like in the posted image.

Comment: Sorry but a bit difficult to see whats going on from here, so i will guess.  The script you added with .css("display","none")  will execute on load, and effect all existing tags (table tr's)  but when you enter the text in the search bar - perhaps the tr's are being dynamically loaded again.  this would mean that you might need to stick the same script inside the event that catches the search text, so that the new generated (blank) trs can be weeded out.

Comment: I cant see where the search bar triggers an event though - perhaps you know.  also it might be a bit cleaner if you could stick the new bit of code in a function and call it where ever you need.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice I hadn't posted all my JS code.

Here is my code for where the event is triggered. I did put that same code within this function to see if it would work from the tr's possibly being dynamically loaded again.

I have added the dashboard.js file where that function is within my question.

Comment: sorry to be saying try this and try that but... try  $(this).css("display","none") instead of .hide()  ...   $tableBody.each(function(index, row) {
    var hasMatch;
    var $row = $(row).text();

    hasMatch = ($row.includes(searchText));
    hasMatch ? $(this).show() : $(this).css("display","none")
  })